# Are SSL Client Certificates well supported by all major browsers?

Tags: security, authentication, web

We're thinking of improving the authentication of some critical webpages with client certificates, but we're not sure whether it's a widely used standard.

Are SSL Client Certificates well supported by all major browsers? In particular, do they work on the following browsers?

- Internet Explorer
- Mozilla Firefox
- Google Chrome
- Apple Safari (Mac and iOS)
- Android Web Browser

(We use Apache on the servers, if that matters)

Comment: Any browser that can access https sites supports certificates.

Comment: @John Could you please confirm you're talking about the client certificates that are used to authenticate the client?

Comment: sorry, I think I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a way of testing all of this, but [this site](https://support.quovadisglobal.com/KB/c5/end-user-certificates.aspx) came up on google with instructions for installing PKCS#12 certificate/key pairs in a number of different situations, [including on the iPhone](https://support.quovadisglobal.com/KB/a64/how-do-i-install-a-digital-certificate-onto-an-iphone.aspx).

It seems that Android only uses PKCS#12 certificates for VPN authentication.  [Here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8196) is the wishlist entry for browser client authentication support using imported certificates.

Answer (score -2):

That depends on the CA (Certificate Authority) and whether they are included as defaults or updates to the various web browsers. You can get a general idea by looking through the default CAs included/identified with the various web browsers.

Non-included CAs will result in a warning screen via the web browsers, which may cause some alarm/concern with some users.

SSL over HTTPS support is generally universal across the contemporary web browsers.

Comment: Do you imply that all browsers support client certificates, and the only problem is that the browser's trusted CA list may not include the one I used (i.e. the same problem server certificates face)?

Comment: Yes, SSL support is practically universal for all contemporary web browsers.

Comment: Are you sure you you're not talking about server certificates?

Comment: Actually, there may be additional warnings if a certificate is not used in the application/use that is has been identified for (if it can be somehow installed in the first place).

Comment: You're talking about something completely different what the OP asked.